# "What is the probability that you will pass a test given that you procrastinate?" with Bayes' theorem

Tags: statistics, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I'm new to Bayes' theorem and I have to make a project explaining it, so I came up with this word problem;

> A student has done 19 tests over two years. For 7 tests, she procrastinated but still passed. For 4 tests, she procrastinated but didn't pass. For 8 tests, she didn't procrastinate and she passed. There were no tests in which she didn't procrastinate and didn't pass. What is the probability that she will pass given that she procrastinates?

You could use Bayes' theorem to solve this, however it's clear that using the conditional probability rule is simpler.
$P(Pass|P)= \frac{P(P∩Pass)}{P(P)} = \frac{7}{11} ≈ 64\%$

Is there a way of altering this problem to make it more complex so that using Bayes' theorem is necessary/simpler and more striaght forward?

Comment: A way to get satisfying Bayes' theorem problems is to reverse the conditionality. For example your experimental probabilities give you the probability that she passes given whether or not she procrastinates. But then what is the probably that she had procrastinated on a specific test, given that she passed it? This gets you what you want.

Comment: You cannot say what the conditional *probability will be* in a new test without something more, but you can find the conditional *proportion was* from this information.  How many times did she procrastinate? (You got that wrong in your attempt - it was not $19$.)  In how many of those procrastinating cases did she pass?  (You got that right in your attempt - it was $7$.) What was the proportion?

Comment: To make it more Bayesian you might instead ask the question: "You pick one of her tests at random and see that she passed it.  What is the probability that she procrastinated before that test?" The calculation approach is similar even if the procrastination happens before the test.

Comment: @Henry thanks, I just fixed it. But still, you can solve it using conditional probability. And what do you mean by "What was the proportion"?

Comment: $\frac7{11}$ was indeed the proportion of tests she passed when she procrastinated .  Similarly $\frac{8}{8}=1$ was the proportion of tests she passed when she did not procrastinate; that does not mean that  she will be almost guaranteed to pass a new test if she does not procrastinate, so it is not a probability.

Comment: @Henry I've never thought about it that way before, as a proportion. So if $\frac7{11}$ is just the proportion, how do we find the probability?

Comment: I suspect the desired answer is $\frac7{11}$.  But there is a whole subject of estimating future parameters from past evidence, as for example in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval

Comment: Got it. By the way, @ Henry @NinadMunshi, can you elaborate more on why reversing the conditional probability will result in a more Bayesian question?

Comment: Because if we rephrase the question at the end like @Henry said, we could still solve with conditional probability. $\frac{P\ (no.\ of \ tests \ she \ passed \ with \ procrastination)}{P\ (no.\ of \ tests \ she \ passed)} = \frac{7}{15} ≈ 47\%$